# Youtubeview after initializing once not initializing again using youtube api

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube-api

In my android tablet app I have one base activity and that activity has 3fragments

all the fragments has a video playing option and all of them are interlinked, means I can switch from one fragment to the other two fragments

when user clicks the video play option it will open a new activity and play the youtube video.

I'm using youtube api and the video is playing well except for sometime

the video id is generated from the url every time in that youtube activity from the url,I have printed the log and I'm checking whether id is created, and it is created

I've used

```
youtubeplayerview.initialize(API_KEY, VideoPlayActivity.this);
```

to initialize the youtubeplayview, and

```
player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
```

inside onInitializationSuccess method to add the view to the youtube view

the problem I'm facing is:

if suppose I play the video from fragment A, it played well and good,
now if i go to fragment B from A and again play the video, it will go on loading but will never go inside the onInitializationSuccess method, but if I debug the code, its going well and good.

does the youtube api needs some delay before starting the video?
I don't have any idea why this is happening and what am i missing

Question 2:
Will the youtube api behaviour differ from system to system???
My app has been integrated with facebook and its been done from another pc, and I'm doing youtube from my pc, the final build has to be from the system which integrated facebook,(I know youtube api key doesn't depend on sha1 key which differs from system to system still want to clear my doubt) will it be a problem with youtube at that time?

any help is favourable

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to see the video in full screen ?

Comment: Nop I can see it in full screen, the problem is the video loads for the first time, but not the second time or the third from different fragments

Comment: Because i already face a similar problem with Youtube api lifecylce and cache. I use [YoutubeStandalonePlayer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeStandalonePlayer) instead. => `YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(MyActivity,DEVELOPER_KEY_ANDROID, id)`

Comment: This same thing happened to my app too. It seemed to work well when I created a new project and just stripped it down to bare minimum and launched an activity which derives from YouTubeBaseActivity and cued a video repeatedly. But when I integrated it into my app, I have the exact same problem as you described. @lithos35 solution of using the standalone player works for me, for the time being so I'll just settle with that.